# ¿Cómo puedo acumular un registro en uno solo dentro de un INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada fases, que coge la primaria de otra tabla llamada proyecto (Queriendo decir que un proyecto tiene varias fases) y que los proyectos también tienen usuarios. Cómo puedo hacer para que al momento de consultar pueda acomodar todas las fases incluidas en un proyecto en un fieldset?.

Esta es mi consulta

```
`$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT idcontacto,nombreCont, apellidoPatCont, apellidoMatCont, correoCont, numLocalCont, numCelularCont, idusuarios, nombre, apellidoPat, apellidoMat, correo, numeroLocal,numeroCelular, idtipoPersona, persona, nombreProyecto, fechaInicio, fechaFin, faltante, avanzado, incentivo, gastosCompra, gastosEnvio, tipoCorte, nombreArchivo, archivo
            FROM `proyecto` p INNER JOIN `contacto` c ON p.contacto_idcontacto = c.idcontacto  INNER JOIN `corte` co ON co.idcorte = p.corte_idcorte  INNER JOIN `usuarios` u ON u.proyecto_idproyecto = p.idproyecto INNER JOIN `tipoPersona` tp ON tp.idtipoPersona = u.tipoPersona_idtipoPersona   INNER JOIN `requisitos` r ON r.usuarios_idusuarios = u.idusuarios 
            where idusuarios = :idusuarios IN (SELECT nombreFase, idfases FROM `fases` f INNER JOIN `proyecto` p ON f.proyecto_idproyecto = p.idproyecto where idusuarios = :idusuarios)";`
```

Utilizo varios INNER JOIN y el DISTINCT. El resultado de la consulta es: si tengo dos fases en un proyecto la consulta la muestra dos veces y las fases por separado.

Este de aquí es mi vista donde quiero meter las fases

```
<div class="grupo" align="left">
                <fieldset>
                <legend> <b>Fases</b></legend>
                    <table>
                        <td><input type="hidden" value="'.$fila['idfases'].'"/></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="'.$fila['nombreFase'].'"/>'.$fila['nombreFase'].'</td>

                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
```

Este es el resultado de mi consulta.
[image: Parte del resultado de consulta]

Notese que la fase si la cambia, puesto que en mi registro, el proyecto tiene dos fases.

Esta es la estructura de mi base de datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, la solución que se me viene a la mente es que crees una subconsulta que te traiga las fases y que esa subconsulta venga concatenada para luego hacer un ciclo con ese concatenado, aqui tienes un link que te puede ayudar para la subconsulta: https://hvivani.com.ar/2012/03/26/sql-concatenar-varios-registros-de-una-columna-en-una-sola-cadena-concatenate-strings-from-a-column-into-a-single-string/

Comment: @Andrés dentro de la subconsulta selecciono lo que es las fases de acuerdo al proyecto? Ese link es de gran ayuda.

Comment: Si, cualquier cosa si aun no lo consigues, actualiza tu pregunta mostrando la estructura de tus tablas para ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias, ya compartí mi modelo. Pude concatenar  pero salían los registros seguidos igual dos veces, osea la consulta dos veces, como muestro en la imagen.

Comment: No creo que tu problema radique en la DB si no en PHP

Comment: es que a tu consulta principal debes borrar INNER JOIN `fases` f ON f.proyecto_idproyecto = p.idproyecto , eso es lo que te genera el duplicado

Comment: ya la he borrado, y pues me quedó, pero es como si las omitiera.  El fieldset no muestra nada

Comment: Al correr la consulta normal en mysql si te muestra resultado?, actualiza tu pregunta con la nueva consulta que tienes para verla

Comment: Esa es la actualización de la consulta, en mysql reemplazo el :idusuarios, por un número de usuario y me aparece  #1241 - Operando debe tener 1 columna(s). Mientras tanto en la vista ya me aparecen errores.

Comment: ya te salio o sigues con el problema?

Comment: Sigo con el. :(

Answer (score 0):

Para concatenar las fases y que todo te salga en una sola fila, seria la sigueinte consulta sql:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT idcontacto,nombreCont, apellidoPatCont, apellidoMatCont, correoCont, numLocalCont, 
    numCelularCont, idusuarios, nombre, apellidoPat, apellidoMat, correo, numeroLocal,numeroCelular, 
    idtipoPersona, persona, nombreProyecto, fechaInicio, fechaFin, faltante, avanzado, incentivo, gastosCompra, 
    gastosEnvio, tipoCorte, nombreArchivo, archivo,
    (SELECT group_concat( nombreFase)AS nmbreFase , group_concat(idfases)AS idfases FROM `fases` f INNER JOIN `proyecto` p ON f.proyecto_idproyecto = p.idproyecto where idusuarios = :idusuarios)
FROM `proyecto` p 
INNER JOIN `contacto` c ON p.contacto_idcontacto = c.idcontacto  
INNER JOIN `corte` co ON co.idcorte = p.corte_idcorte  
INNER JOIN `usuarios` u ON u.proyecto_idproyecto = p.idproyecto 
INNER JOIN `tipoPersona` tp ON tp.idtipoPersona = u.tipoPersona_idtipoPersona   
INNER JOIN `requisitos` r ON r.usuarios_idusuarios = u.idusuarios 
WHERE idusuarios = :idusuarios;
```

Ya después en php separas el concatenado para que te haga la lista de fases.

Comment: intenté hacer esta consulta en mysql y me sigue marcando  #1241 - Operando debe tener 1 columna(s). . Realice un ejemplo para usar el GROUP_CONCAT y sacar el concatendao con explode() de PHP pero al parecer no me coge nada

Comment: Fue mi error, a la subconsulta le falta la relación con la tabla usuario, para que te pueda hacer el filtro.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT idcontacto,nombreCont, apellidoPatCont, apellidoMatCont, correoCont, numLocalCont, numCelularCont, idusuarios, nombre, apellidoPat, apellidoMat, correo, numeroLocal,numeroCelular, idtipoPersona, persona, nombreProyecto, fechaInicio, fechaFin, faltante, avanzado, incentivo, gastosCompra, gastosEnvio, tipoCorte, nombreArchivo, archivo,
    (SELECT group_concat( nombreFase)AS nombreFase , group_concat(idfases)AS idfases FROM `fases` f INNER JOIN `proyecto` p ON f.proyecto_idproyecto=p.idproyecto INNER JOIN `usuarios` u ON u.proyecto_idproyecto = p.idproyecto where idusuarios = 1)

Comment: FROM `proyecto` p 
INNER JOIN `contacto` c ON p.contacto_idcontacto = c.idcontacto  
INNER JOIN `corte` co ON co.idcorte = p.corte_idcorte  
INNER JOIN `usuarios` u ON u.proyecto_idproyecto = p.idproyecto 
INNER JOIN `tipoPersona` tp ON tp.idtipoPersona = u.tipoPersona_idtipoPersona   
INNER JOIN `requisitos` r ON r.usuarios_idusuarios = u.idusuarios 
WHERE idusuarios = 1;



------- >
Si se lo he puesto, ya que me marcaba idusuario indefinido.
Así es como la escribo en mysql y marca el error #1241, disculpa la estructura.